# Keeping a class on the last hovered item in a list

Tags: jquery, html

I have a nav that looks like this

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="first active">
            <a href="#">nav 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">nav 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">nav 1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">nav 1.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">nav 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">nav 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">nav 2.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">nav 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">nav 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">nav 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">nav 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The active class is always initially set in the HTML. Currently using this really simple function to add/remove the active class on the list item, depending on which one the mouse is hovered over:

```
function primaryNav() { 

    var navigationLink = $('nav ul li');

    navigationLink.hover(function() { 
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

}
```

This is fine to switch classes, I am just unsure how to make sure the class stays on the li when the mouse leaves the nav area entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just remove all the active ones before setting a new one:

```
function primaryNav() { 
    var navigationLink = $('nav ul li');
    navigationLink.mouseenter(function() { 
        navigationLink.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
       //dont do anything
    });
}
```

Comment: This could be problem if class "active" is being used else where on different element...

Comment: I had to change var navigationLink to $('nav > ul > li'), so that the list items in the nested list didn't take the class. Thanks this works perfectly.

Comment: @theorise - you can go with whichever solution you want, but the reason I wrote my answer below the way I did was so that it only changed sibling `li` tags so nested lists or `.active` classes being used elsewhere were not affected.

Answer (score 3):

You can just remove the class from all other li tags upon hover and add it to this one:

```
$('nav ul li').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

This method has the advantage that it only affects the sibling `li` tags so it won't affect any sub-items or any other items in the page with the `"active"` class.

Comment: I just noticed your comment I'll take a better look when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the last hover item to keep the "Active" class, right? If so, try this:

```
function primaryNav() { 

    var navigationLink = $('nav ul li');

    navigationLink.mouseover(function() { 
        $('nav ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

}
```

Also, for future reference, when using Hover() you do not need to specify mouseout or hoverout, you can just chain the out function to in function via " , " comma.